# How to schedule tasks when computer is off

Tags: r, windows, scheduled-tasks

I have a very basic question.
I have built with R a script than can send me reports by email.
I then used task scheduler to send those emails on specific times.
But now I would like to automate more frequently these scripts (let's say every 2 hours) and to only receive an email when the alert I created in my script (a flag) is on, and this even when my pc is off.
As task scheduler won't work, does that mean I need a server or something ?
Does it have a cost ? I am complete newbie in that area. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you can use [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/), [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/), [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/free) (has free tier) to run your program on a server.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you would need a separate server for when your computer is off. I might suggest the Free Tier services from Amazon Web Services.