# How do I automate scraping then alerting?

Tags: python, automation

I am able to scrape a website with python/beautifulsoup script. Nothing fancy. Now I'd like to automate that scraping then send myself an alert (either mail / SMS or some phone notification). The frequency would be quite low (weekly, maybe daily if there is a significant change from previous day).

It doesn't seems to be too difficult to build some solution with the right libraries (ie continuously running a python script that would perfom some action after a certain date). But I am questionning the 'hardware' part. How do I make sure that the script is continuously running ? Do I have to use a small pc like a raspberry pi and ensure that it is continually running / connected to the internet ? Could I do that more reliably with a (cheap) online service ? (Or do I have to review the idea of continuously running the script ?)

Comment: You can try Heroku?

Comment: You can set it with Windows Scheduler to run daily. It doesn't sound like you need to have it running 24/7 to monitor changes on-the-fly if your reports will be less frequent.

Comment: @Reti43: but that would mean that my pc need to be constantly running, no ?

Comment: It would need to run for the scheduled time. If it's off, *I think* it'll execute it when it first gets a chance, which will be next time you boot. You can also set wake calls if you're in hibernation then. But if you want something more consistent, you can look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47743415/how-to-schedule-tasks-when-computer-is-off), which is also what coderoftheday suggested.